# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, pyowm

Python 3.86
Windows 7
Pycharm

```
pip freeze:
certifi=2020.12.5
chardet=4.0.0
geojson=2.5.0
idna=2.10
pyowm=3.1.1
PySocks=1.7.1
pyTelegramBotAPI=3.7.4
requests=2.25.1
urllib3=1.26.2
```

Сижу через tutorial-env
Мой код:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

import telebot

owm = OWM('ключ owm')
bot = telebot.TeleBot("мой api от botfather")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def send_echo(message):

    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather

    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    wind = w.wind()['speed']

    answer = 'Влад п***р, в городе ' + message.text + ' сейчас ' + w.detailed_status() + '\n'
    answer += 'Влад ша**ва, температура сейчас в районе ' + str(temp) + ' градусов, а скорость ветра где-то ' + str(wind) + ' м/с' + '\n\n'

    if temp < -10:
        answer += 'Влад петух, на улице сейчас жуткий холод. Лучше вообще никуда не выходить!'
    elif temp < 0:
        answer += 'Влад г****н, на улице сейчас холод. Лучше одеться потеплее!'
    elif temp < 10:
        answer += 'Влад пи***ас, на улице сейчас холодновато. Накинь куртку!'
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += 'Влад про******ка, на улице сейчас прохладно. Накинь кофту!'
    elif temp > 20:
        answer += 'Влад гомосексуалист, на улице тепло или даже жарко. Можно выходить в шортах.'


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

В консоли выдаёт это сразу после отправки боту первого сообщения

```
(tutorial-env) C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects\tutorial-env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 455, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects\tutorial-env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects\tutorial-env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 479, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects\tutorial-env\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 118, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\projects\tutorial-env\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in send_echo
    answer = 'Влад п***р, в городе ' + message.text + ' сейчас ' + w.detailed_status() + '\n'
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

(tutorial-env) C:\Users\6417\PycharmProjects\helloworld>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w.detailed_status` это строка, а не метод поэтому вызывать её не надо. Просто уберите скобки